# ntheorem style change for heading

Tags: formatting, theorems, ntheorem

Im using the packages `ntheorem` and `framed` to create boxes like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1g1z.png). [image: ntheorem] Does anyone know how to change the heading to the following order:

name. counter: parameter

For example: **Erg. 2: Erwerbshierarchie regspr. Vnt. der Bezugsphoneme**

My actual settings are:

```
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[hyperref, amsmath, amsthm, framed, thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\smallskip\scriptsize\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont\scriptsize}
\theoremindent0.5cm
\newframedtheorem{erg}{Erg.}
```

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The braces are actually hardcoded in the definition of the `break` style, so the definition needs to be changed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[hyperref, amsmath, amsthm, framed, thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\makeatletter
\renewtheoremstyle{break}%
  {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
          ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}%
  {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
%           ##1\ ##2\ (##3)\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}% DELETED
          ##1\ ##2:\ ##3\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}% NEW
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\smallskip\scriptsize\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont\scriptsize}
\theoremindent0.5cm
\newframedtheorem{erg}{Erg.}

\begin{document}

\begin{erg}[Description]
Some text.
\end{erg}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to keep the original `break` style,then you could define this as your own style using `\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}` and then use `\theoremstyle{mystyle}` in the definition of `erg`

Comment: lockstep, do you know how to shrink the inner space between the textparts and the border? Furthermore, is there some option to widen the space leftside and rightside out of the border?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the intricacies of framed boxes. However, have a look at the [mdframed](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package.